# How to decode bytes object from FTP retrbinary function in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm pulling in a file from FTP that I want to put in a Pandas dataframe eventually. I am stuck up on decoding the output into a string that can be read by `pd.read_csv`.

```
def fetch_data():
    ftp = FTP('hostname')
    ftp.login('username','password')

    files = ftp.nlst()

    output = []

    for file in files:
        filedata = open("C:/Users/USER/" + file, 'w+b')
        ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + file, filedata.write)
        ftp.quit()

        decoded_data = bytes.decode(filedata)
        output_frame = pd.read_csv(decoded_data)
        output.append(output_frame)
```

Here's the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dataframe.py", line 70, in <module> fetch_data()
  File "dataframe.py", line 32, in fetch_data 
      decoded_data = bytes.decode(filedata)
TypeError: descriptor 'decode' requires a 'bytes' object but received a'_io.BufferedRandom'
```

I think I am misunderstanding the binary information coming from `ftp.retrbinary`.

What's the best way to decode this information so that it can be read by `pd.read_csv`?

Comment: Can you try closing the file first `filedata.close()` and then reading again before decoding like this - `file_data = open("path/to/file/",'rb')`

Comment: Did so, same traceback but moved two lines down with the addition of the lines you suggested.

Comment: @Floydian I also confirmed that the file is getting downloaded and put into the directory. I could just reference the file path directly in the short term but ultimately I'm not sure what the name of these files will be on any given day since it's a daily reporting upload that feeds into business intelligence dashboards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like for what you want you could simply use pd.read_csv by passing it the path to your downloaded file instead:

```
output_frame = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/USER/" + file)
```

Comment: I think I accidentally deleted that space when I was formatting for StackOverflow, I have it as you do in my working version. I'll update the original post. Still got the same traceback.

Comment: What is the extension of the downloaded file? You also say that it works if you reference the path directly. How does the code look like if you do so? And won't the path always be simply "C:/Users/USER/" + file? I didn't understand this part.

Comment: When I say "reference the path directly," I mean to read the .csv once it's downloaded. So it would be something like `output_frame = pd.read_csv("C:/User/USER/file.csv")`. Ultimately though, I won't necessarily know the name of the .csv which is why I'm trying to do it all without actually using the downloaded file path. I also can't just feed `filedata` into `pd.read_csv` because it's encoded which is what I'm trying to solve.

Comment: I see. Still, from what I understood the name of the file will be its name as it is in the FTP server (file), so you'd be able to retrieve its name whatever it is, save it with that name, and read it into a dataframe referencing path + file.csv.

Comment: Got it. So basically just skip the decoding step and call the file object I created from the FTP from the directory isntead. Everything seems so simple once you hear it from someone else... thanks.

Comment: Great. I've edited my answer so that users facing the same issue are presented this simple alternative. If you think it is a solution, please consider accepting it as the answer. Thanks.